# 3 people Red hat Blue hat word problem.

Tags: logic, word-problem

I am stuck of this question, for longer that I should be and also convinced that there is a typo in the question.

I am going to take a screen shot of the question as to make sure I don’t miss type the information.

> [image]

Now my problem lie with the last part of the question, what I cannot figure is how the middle knows for sure that he has a red how the reason for how is below.

So the possible permutations of hat are

${RRR , RRB , RBR , BRR , BBB , BBR , BRB , RBB}$

The question says **at least 1 blue hat** which to me mean that they could all have blue hats.

Now if I work backwards and think how would the back person know what colour hat they have then that would be $RRB$ but the back person doesn’t  know, so that leaves

$RBR , BRR , BBB , BBR , BRB , RBB$

and this is where I am stuck because how can M know his hat is red. One conclusion I thought off is if the middle man has said "if, back don’t know his hat, then he must have then he must not have a blue hat", so then that would remove $BBB,BRB,RBB$ and then left with $RBR,BRB$ so then M must have a red hat.

But this logic breaks down because M cannot assume that B has a blue hat from he just saying he dose not know the colour of his hat because, the B would not know the colour of his hat if there was a $BBB$.

So I honestly cannot see how M knows for sure he has a red hat, from the information given.

So is there a typo in this question.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If B doesn't know, the either M or F must have a $B$ hat, so M would know if his hat was $B$ if F had a $R$ hat.  It looks like statement c. should have at least one person has a $R$ hat, so the answer would come out M knows he has a $R$ hat.

Comment: This Is what i have been thinking this whole time, excusse the pun but it the only logicall way I could see this.

Comment: Part (c). After the claim of the back man, we have for FMB only the possibilities with at least one blue hat for FM, i.e. BR* or RB* or BB*. Only in the case R*=RB* the man in the middle can deduce something, namely that his hat is **blue**. The problem was already suspect for me from the second the logicians were *randomly* lined up...

Comment: @dan_fulea my I ask what you mean by R*=RB*, did you mean BR*=RB* ?

Comment: There may be a typo or typos. There are two likely possibilities for this to make sense:


Typo (1) As someone already suggested in the comments, if c read: if at least 1 person had a *red* hat, in which case the back person not knowing and the middle person inferring correctly that they have a red hat would be consistent with states $BRR$ or $BRB$.


Typo (2) If c stated that *at most* one person has 1 blue hat, then the puzzle also makes sense, i.e. it's description would be consistent with $RRR$ or $RRB$.